# Fatal error: call to undefined method getMyLogs()

Tags: php

My local server can find the controller class, but once live I get the following error:

> Fatal error: call to undefined method getMyLogs();

To access the method I do the following:

```
$activity = new PointsController();
$logs = $activity->getMyLogs($_SESSION['id']);
```

Now the method itself:

```
public function getMyLogs($id)
{
    $db = new DB();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users_activity` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id ORDER BY `log_date` DESC';

    $results = $db->get($sql, array(
        ':user_id'  =>  $id
    ));

    return $results;
}
```

As said, it is working like a charm on my localhost. Once I upload it live the server respond with the error I mentioned.

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do a `var_dump()` of the `$activity` variable once you have registered the class to it, what does it return? Also, have you ensured that the filepath to the `PointsController()` class, is the same on localhost and live? or that the live server is pointing to the correct file on your live system?

Comment: When I do a `var_dump()` on `$activity` I get the following: `object(PointsController)[10]`. Yes it is autoloaded. Another class is called in a div above, so it should work.. But it doens't -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Apperantly I was uploading the files into the wrong folder. The old classes couldn't be overwritten this way. So it makes sence now.

Well, makes me to revise my folder structure...